# Vue and lint on run: how to configure?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, visual-studio-code

When executing `npm run serve`. I got a LOT of warnings from a linter that I am not able to find and configure

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
warning: Insert `;` (prettier/prettier) at src\main.js:1:22:
> 1 | import Vue from "vue"
```

For example, My VsCode is setup to use 4 space as tab, in the Prettier extension, but when running the same loader warn me because it wants I use 2 spaces indentation.

I am not able to identify WHERE / HOW configure the eslint-loader itself to config/disable the rules as my need.

```
warning: Replace `····` with `··` (prettier/prettier) at src\main.js:22:1:
  20 | new Vue({
  21 |     router,
> 22 |     store,
     | ^
  23 |     render: h => h(App)
  24 | }).$mount("#app")
```

I want to disable this for example, I want to force 4 space indentation check, not 2 spaces!

I've the Vetur extension, and it's setup to use prettier

Prettier is setup to use 4 spaces tab. So I thinks that settings I need now are not vscode-related.

Comment: Do you not have a `prettierrc` file, or something to that effect?

Comment: I have no prettierrc file; I read it was ignored by vscode so I didn't try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINAL SOLUTION**- Credits: https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#editor-integrations, and a lot of time trying and tring and trying by myself

I disabled prettier extension and disable auto formatting on vs code.

I added this snippet to *workspace* config (not globally !!!!)

```
{
    "eslint.validate": [
        {
            "language": "vue",
            "autoFix": true
        },
        {
            "language": "javascript",
            "autoFix": true
        },
        {
            "language": "javascriptreact",
            "autoFix": true
        }
    ],
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "vetur.validation.template": false
}
```

Plus, configure prettier/prettier on `.eslintrc.js` file.

For example, see how I am using `prettier/prettier` is the `rules` section:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    extends: [
        "plugin:vue/recommended",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "prettier/vue",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    ],
    rules: {
        "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
        "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
        "prettier/prettier":[
            "error", 
            {
                "tabWidth"  : 4,
                "semi" : false,
            }
        ]
    },
    parserOptions: {
        parser: "babel-eslint"
    }
}
```

I have prettier and eslint extensions installed on VsCode as said in my question post.

> See available options here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

In this way, the configuration is working both on vscode AND is working as lint-on-run  as I wanted.

Great !

Comment: do we have to create this .eslintrc.js file?

if yes, then where?

Comment: .eslintrc.js file is located in project's root. It's created by vue-cli when you start a new project.